# Alternative to LAG function

Tags: sas

My dataset is structured like this:

```
ID, Order Date, Delivery Date, Flag
1, 10/03/12, 15/03/12, 
1, 17/03/12, 20/03/12, 1
```

I want to be able to calculate the date difference between the first occurring delivery date and subsequent order dates. Eventual aim is group these records with an identifier.

Have tried the monotonic() with monotonic()+1 for a self join - but the problem with this is that each ID can have multiple different numbers of rows needing to be grouped together. Am using SAS Enterprise Guide 7 - unfortunately LAG is not available.

An example of what I'm looking to achieve is:

```
ID, Order Date, Deliv Date, Order Date_1, Deliv Date_1, DateDIFF(Deliv Date - Order Date_1)
1, 10/03/12, 15/03/12, 17/03/12, 20/03/12, 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This can be done using SAS `Retain` functionality when grouping by the `ID`. Please and an examples of the desired data and I will give you the code for it.

Comment: The desired dataset would retain 1 row per ID and have multiple columns for each order and delivery dates depending on the date difference.

Comment: Ok, Please add an example including sample data. I will post an initial answer. It sounds like you want to transpose the data as well.

Comment: IF ID 1 had 3 orders, would you want 3 columns for DateDiff? consider the data example in my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by LAG is not available? LAG is only 'not available' in PROC SQL, a data step will work fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `proc sort` the data in descending order by `Delivery_Date` then `retain` the values of the previous record while grouping by `ID` in order to calculate the difference.

Code:

```
 data have;
   infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
   informat id 11. Order_Date ddmmyy8. Delivery_Date ddmmyy8. flag 11.;
   format Order_Date ddmmyy8. Delivery_Date ddmmyy8.;
   input ID Order_Date Delivery_Date Flag;
   datalines;
1, 10/03/12, 15/03/12,.
1, 17/03/12, 20/03/12, 1
2, 10/03/12, 10/03/12,.
2, 17/03/12, 20/03/12, 1
2, 10/03/12, 27/03/12,1
2, 17/03/12, 23/03/12, 1
run;

proc sort data=have; 
  by id descending Delivery_Date ; 
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  retain nxt_date;
  if first.id=1 then do; 
    nxt_date = Delivery_Date; 
    diff=0; 
  end;
  else do; 
    prv_date=nxt_date;
    diff=nxt_date-Delivery_Date;
    nxt_date = Delivery_Date;
  end;
  format prv_date ddmmyy8.
  drop nxt_date;
run;
```

Output:

```
id=1 Order_Date=17/03/12 Delivery_Date=20/03/12 flag=1 diff=0 prv_date=.
id=1 Order_Date=10/03/12 Delivery_Date=15/03/12 flag=. diff=5 prv_date=20/03/12
id=2 Order_Date=10/03/12 Delivery_Date=27/03/12 flag=1 diff=0 prv_date=.
id=2 Order_Date=17/03/12 Delivery_Date=23/03/12 flag=1 diff=4 prv_date=27/03/12
id=2 Order_Date=17/03/12 Delivery_Date=20/03/12 flag=1 diff=3  prv_date=23/03/12
id=2 Order_Date=10/03/12 Delivery_Date=10/03/12 flag=. diff=10 prv_date=20/03/12
```